# Dropbox Chooser postMessage failure

Tags: cordova, dropbox-api, postmessage, inappbrowser

I'm building a web app based on Cordova, and am trying to integrate with the [Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js).

I'm using the [InAppBrowser plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) to open the page from my web server that includes the code for opening the the Chooser.

This approach works for the (mobile) web, but fails in the InAppBrowser with these symptoms:

**1**: When the chooser popup window is opened there is an error in the console about a failed `postMessage`:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://mywebserver.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.dropbox.com').
```

**2**: When I pick something in the chooser and press 'Choose', or just hit 'Cancel', another instance of that message is put in the console, and this message is displayed to the user:

> Unable to close this window. Please close it manually and return to the previous site.

I've tried many different things including using the `_system` target for the InAppBrowser, but then I'm left with no way to communicate back to the app the results of the picker. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

---

For the record, and FWIW, `Dropbox.isBrowserSupported()` returns `true` for the InAppBrowser.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dropbox Chooser isn't currently supported in scenarios like this, e.g., using Cordova, due to some issues with cross-window communication, as you've seen. We're tracking this as a feature request though.

Comment: Thanks for the update Greg. Is there anything that can be done to "up vote" that feature request, and/or get a preview?

(FWIW, for the integration I've got working with Google Drive, I found I needed use `window.location.assign` instead of `window.open` for all the steps through the auth flows and the picking so that the InAppBrowser wouldn't lose it's place and I could get the selection back up to my app.)

Comment: I've already recorded this post internally as a vote for supporting it, though I can't say if or when it would be implemented unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks again Greg ... Given that I've got the environment already set up, is there a way to have access to the code to poke around with it (from the uglified code I've already got some changes in mind I'd love to check out).

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have any such resources publicly available.

Comment: @IdanAdar Have you figured out a workaround for this?

Comment: @jsplaine - we ended up using the `_system` browser, and giving the user a button to push after picking their file that navigates to a custom link type registered for the app that the app is then able to parse the necessary data out of ... it's a **huge** jump in complexity, but it worked.